# LinkedIn share post URL changed and gives error message: 'It's not you it's us, give it another try please.'

Tags: wordpress, url, linkedin-api, sharing

I have a wordpress website https:www.x-equo.nl and we have single job which we want to share with linkedin. If we click ont he share button, we get the error message:

'It's not you it's us, give it another try please.'.

When I have a look at the URL created:

https://www.linkedin.com/cws/share/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.x-equo.nl%2Fvacature%2Ffinancieel-administratief-medewerker-6%2F

I see that the "css/share" part in the URL is different than another website we have in which the sharing does work.

What is going wrong here? How can we change the share link URL so linkedin will accept it?

Hope anyone can help us.

Thank you I advance

We tried reading a lot of other helpdesk but non of them seem logic.

Comment: I am facing same issue on my website. Can you please help me to get solution?

Comment: was it showing this error because the link was fresh and probably linkedin did not crawl it yet?

Answer (score 0):

The following URL format works perfectly for me...

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.x-equo.nl%2Fvacature%2Ffinancieel-administratief-medewerker-6%2F
```

And the URL you have will simply redirect to the URL above.  You have correctly encoded the URL, so, that's not the problem.  But, yes, it definitely works:

[image]

Source: **[Official LinkedIn Shareable Documentation](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en)**.

Not sure if your page is loading correctly?  Test it out by inserting your URL into the [**LinkedIn Post Inspector**](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/).